# Solutions of $Ax=b$ of square matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

If A is a $5 \times 5$ matrix and the equation $Ax = b$ is consistent
for every b in $R^5$; is it possible that for some $b$, the equation
$Ax = b$ has more than one solution? Why or why not?

Comment: does "consistent" mean that exists a solution?

Comment: The column space is all of $\Bbb R^5$. What is the null space then? If $x\ne y$ were two solutions to $Ax=b$, what can you say about $A(x-y)$?

Comment: @Exodd Yes, if a system of linear equations is consistent, then there is either a unique solution or infinite solutions.

Answer (score 1):

No. The matrix is invertible, and inverses are unique. So

$$Ax=b \iff x=A^{-1}b$$

is the **unique** vector $x$ satisfying that equality.

Answer (score 1):

No. By the rank nullity theorem, the map $x \mapsto Ax$ is onto only if it is also one-to-one.